# Trying to read an int into a struct, but it returns a segfault?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

So I have this code which is reading in strings and applying them to their respective struct members fine, but as soon as I get into reading an int, my program crashes and returns a segfault. However if I assign a variable a value, then pass that value into the struct, it works fine. If I assign a variable a value, overwrite that value with a scanf, then pass it into the struct, it segfaults again.

```
void createcompetitor() {
    struct competitor *newcompetitor = malloc(sizeof (struct competitor));
    if (newcompetitor == NULL)
        return;
    printf("Please enter the competitor's first name\n");
    fgets(newcompetitor->firstname, 25, stdin);
    printf(newcompetitor->firstname);
    printf("Please enter the competitor's last name\n");
    fgets(newcompetitor->lastname, 35, stdin);
    printf(newcompetitor->lastname);
    printf("Please enter the competitor's address\n");
    fgets(newcompetitor->address, 105, stdin);
    printf(newcompetitor->address);
    printf("Please enter the competitor's age\n");
    scanf("%d", &newcompetitor->phonenumber);
    scanf("%c");
    printf("%d", newcompetitor->age);
    printf("Please enter the competitor's phone number\n");
    scanf("%d", &newcompetitor->phonenumber);
    scanf("%c");
    printf("%d", newcompetitor->phonenumber);
    printf("Please enter the competitor's registration number\n");
    scanf("%d", &newcompetitor->competitornumber);
    scanf("%c");
    printf("%d", newcompetitor->competitornumber);
}
```

Sorry for super messy code, I'm just trying to figure out what exactly is going on with the program.

EDIT:
The struct definition is

```
struct competitor {
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[30];
    char address [100];
    int age;
    int phonenumber;
    int competitornumber;
    struct competitor *next;
};
```

Comment: (1) Your function leaks, even if it doesn't segfaults. (2) Where is the struct definition?

Comment: `scanf("%c");` --> `scanf("%*c");` (or delete this (Except the last)).

Comment: They are to catch dangling \n, is there a better way?

Comment: Also There is a mismatch in the assumed buffer size. E.g `20` <-> `25`

Comment: So do I release newcompetitor before the function ends? What if I were to put the struct into a linkedlist? Would that no longer be considered leaking?

Comment: Tips: 1- use `#define` for constant array sizes (prevents mismatches). 2- Pass `struct competitor` as a reference and allocate it outside the function.

Comment: You member array `fisrtname` is only `20 chars` and yet you passed `25` to `fgets`. You are doing this with all other member arrays. If input is larger than 20 then you go out of bound. The whole point of `fputs` is not to go out of bound by providing it with buffer size.

Comment: Updated fix the buffer size and removed all %c catches, but now the first int is, I assume, reading in \n as its value and returning 0 no matter what I input. Is there a better way to catch dangling newlines than %c?

Comment: @AndrewHaworth if you put the newly allocated pointer into a linked list, then of course it it no longer a leak, as long as you free it when you free the linked list..

Comment: Stop updating the code to fix errors you are reported about. This isn't a forum, you are invaliding answers.

Comment: Noted. Sorry about that. Will re-insert the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that mismatch

```
char firstname[20];
```

And

```
fgets(newcompetitor->firstname, 25, stdin);
```

You allow writing to outside of the array boundaries, that's undefined behavior.

`scanf("%c");` is another culprit.

`scanf` reads input from stdin and attempts to write it to the address it was passed for the parameter, but you didn't pass any address!

The behavior of your entire program is undefined. Be thankful it only crashed.

If you intend to wait for user interaction before continuing, specify in the format to `scnaf` that the character should be read, but not written anywhere. Like this:

```
`scanf("%*c");`
```

This however is a brittle "waiting for user interaction" technique. So bear that in mind.

Comment: Those are there to catch dangling \n, is there another way to do that?

Comment: @AndrewHaworth - Read this for instance http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392

Answer (score 1):

Your segfault is most probably caused by

```
printf(newcompetitor->firstname);
```

`printf()` should be used like this:

```
printf("%s\n", newcompetitor->firstname);
```

You can use it with one argument if and only if you just have a string literal with no variables, otherwise you need to provide both `format string` and proper number of `variable names`.

Comment: And most compilers, when you ask them for warnings, would have noticed that

Comment: There's no guarantee that's what segfaults. You can't tell that without seeing user input. The second form is better because it prevents the user from inputting control characters, that's true. But it is not a source of UB off the bat.

Comment: @StoryTeller Most of the time when you go out of bound in a string, just a few bytes later you have a `NULL` character and that causes some jumble data to be appended to your actual string, and he has strings after one another, so when he goes out of bound in `firstname` at worst his string is appended with `lastname`. But you are right about the last one, there is no guarantee that a `NULL` character is present until his program reaches the end of paged memory although in most cases, as I already mentioned, there is.

Comment: Immaterial. Going out of bounds has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Since I *think* that going out of bound is not the culprit, I backed the idea that going out of bound is not the cause of problem. So that's what my answer has to do with going out of bound.

Comment: If going out of bounds is not the culprit, what does your long response have to do with what I've said.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I never intended to offend you in anyway, those were just my thoughts. But I do apologize if I did.

Comment: I'm not offended. I just don't follow what you are trying to explain. NVM, however.